# Changing request level for google project

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-authentication

How do I lower the requested access level of an existing google project?
It's currently asking for:

- View your email address
- View your basic profile info
- Manage your contacts

When all I really want is to authenticate a user for login purposes, and I think all I need for that is:

- Have offline access

Comment: its the scopes that dictate what access is requested.

Comment: and how do I change that?

Comment: At the very least, all I want is "View basic profile info"

Comment: its part of the code you are using in your application  check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the parameters you are passing when you create a credential is called `scope`, and contains a list of each of the services your users must authorize.

From [the OAuth 2.0 docs](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.client.OAuth2WebServerFlow-class.html), `scope` contains a `string or iterable of strings`. Change it to the new scopes you want.